# Homomorphic $\bmod p$ operation

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, paillier

Let $E(m)$ a be the encryption  operation using Paillier encryption scheme. Let $N$ be the public key and $p$ be a large prime number, such that $p<N$.

**Question**: Is there any protocol, that given $E(m)$ can compute homomorphic $\mod p$, so after decryption we would a message in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Or is there any multi-party computation protocol that can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any protocol, that given $E(m)$ can compute homomorphic $E(m \bmod p)?$

If there were a way to perform that operation (for any $p>1$ relatively prime to $N$) without the Pallier private key being involved, then you have just shown that Pallier is Fully Homomorphic; that is, you can homomorphicly implement any computation; at the very least, by doing homomophic circuit evalutation.

One approach to show this is to implement a NAND function, which we can do as follows:

$$\textit{NAND}(x, y) = 1 + p^{-1} \cdot ( \lambda(x + y) \bmod p - \lambda(x+y))$$

where:

- All the operations are done homomorphically, for example, $x + y$ means the homomorphic addition of $x$ and $y$
- $\lambda$ is an integer $p > \lambda \ge p/2$
- $p^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $p$ modulo $N$

All the computations included in the NAND definition are additions, subtractions, multiplications by the constants $\lambda$ and $p^{-1}$ (all of which can be performed homomorphicly within Pallier), and the $\bmod p$ operation, which we are assuming also can be performed homomorphicly.

And, if we evaluate NAND (assuming that $x, y$ are constrained to be either 0 or 1, we find that if either $x, y$ are encrypted 0 (or both are), NAND evaluated to encrypted 1; if both are 1, it evaluates to an encrypted 0.

And, NAND is known to be complete; we can construct any circuit be a sufficiently large pile of them.  That is, we can design a circuit to evaluate our function (e.g. SHA-3), and then give as inputs as a series of encrypted 0's and 1's, and get the output as a series of encrypted 0's and 1's.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer is not very clear, so I guess it is not possible?

Comment: @user153465: I haven't shown that it's not possible - I have shown that if it's possible, then you have a Very Significant Result.

Comment: thank you. But it is possible when we use FHE?

Comment: @user153465: FHE, by definition, allows you to evaluation any function homomorphically, so yes...

Comment: @user153465 here is an (somewhat advanced..) paper, whose point is to show you can bootstrap FHE somewhat quicker when you *very carefully* arrange the homomorphic computation of the modular reduction function. If nothing else, this should be a good example to demonstrate that **(i)** mod is computable under FHE, and **(ii)** it's actually non-trivial to do it as efficiently as possible! **Paper URL:** https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/polyboot.pdf

Comment: Btw: @poncho Nice proof. Haven't seen this before. =)

Comment: Thank you, I'm wondering if any interactive protocol that allows us to do that without involving FHE.

Comment: @DanielApon: actually, it's not hard to extend this proof to show that Pallier, along with (just about) any nonlinear homomorphic function, (that is, a function that can't be expressed in the form $cX+d \bmod N$), is FHE; the "just about" term is there to handle odd cases where knowledge of where the nonlinearity happens would allow you to factor $N$ (and hence can't be disclosed).

Comment: Yeah -- $\bmod$ is definitely (highly) non-linear, so needs FHE to be computed homomorphically. On the other hand, I hadn't ever considered what happens when you append an operation *aside from MULT* (or the basic Boolean operations in general) to an additively-homomorphic-only scheme. Cool to see; thanks! =)